# Page Auto Refreshes After Selecting An Options

Tags: java, html, shopify, liquid

New to coding, just a quick question. I have this code, this is a sidebar filter option. Now what i want to happen is after selecting an option the page refreshes. What code should i add? Thanks in advance

```
<style>
  .mobile_sidebar {
    background-color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="mobile_sidebar">
    {% if template contains 'collection' %}
        {% include 'collection_sidebar' %}
    {% endif %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to add some javascript to the page.  The JQuery library might be able to help you in this respect (although there are many ways to do this).

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(".mobile_sidebar").on("click", function () { window.location.reload(); }
</script>
```

NOTE: I didn't test this.

Comment: You'll need to load the JQuery library through another script tag first.

Comment: Thank you! this worked, and you are correct. i need to run this through another script tag. One more question, how to use this to refresh only the parent page?